# Find $f^{(k)}(0)$ in terms of derivatives of $g(x)$ at $0$

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x) = g(x^n)$, find $f^{(k)}(0)$ in terms of derivatives of $g(x)$ at $0$.

My book says the answer is $$f^{(k)}(0) = \begin{cases}0, &k \neq nl \\\dfrac{g^{(l)}(0)(nl)!}{l!}, &k = nl, \end{cases}$$ but how do we prove that? This question was given in the context of Taylor polynomials and in particular that the Taylor polynomial of $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$ of degree $4n+2$ at $0$ is $$x^2-\dfrac{x^6}{3!}+\dfrac{x^{10}}{5!}-\cdots+(-1)^n \dfrac{x^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}.$$

Comment: What happens to the Taylor polynomial when you take $k$ derivatives? Under what conditions will there be a constant term, and what will its value be?

Comment: ([This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886525/) appears to be a specific case of the one asked here.)

Comment: After trying to produce a derivation to this formula for quite some time...and unintentionally venturing into the field of combinatorics...I believe it is the case that there is no way of expressing this function for an arbitrary $x$ in a deterministic fashion. You can algorithmically produce the next round of terms for each derivative action (i.e. starting with $k=1$, then going $k=2$, then going $\cdots$ etc), but if you were to ask what terms are found when $k=80$, short of going through all $79$ predecessor computations, you will not be able to produce an answer.

Comment: Combinatoric compositions, partition functions, etc all end up being relevant to explore this derivation. Given that the 'book' you reference is likely Spivak's *Calculus*, and no such education on this matter is contained within this book, I would altogether ignore part $b$ and $c$ of this problem, which is Problem 8 of Chapter 20 (at least in the 4th edition)